# MySQL Workbench generates combined primary key with unnecessary unique constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, composite-primary-key

I have a problem during SQL generation of my database diagram from MySQL Workbench (UNIQUE constraints are added in every field from combined primary key).

I have following diagram: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3843729/baza.png

Moreover, it has following properties set: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3843729/indexes.png

SQL generated:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`User_has_Menu` (
 `User_id` BIGINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 `Menu_id` BIGINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`, `Menu_id`),
INDEX `fk_User_has_Menu_Menu1_idx` (`Menu_id` ASC),
INDEX `fk_User_has_Menu_User1_idx` (`User_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_User_has_Menu_User1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`)
REFERENCES `test`.`User` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_User_has_Menu_Menu1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`Menu_id`)
REFERENCES `test`.`Menu` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As you can see, 'User_id' and 'Menu_id' have **UNIQUE** keyword, so as a result I cannot insert single user_id (or menu_id) in two rows, for example:

```
insert into user_has_menu (user_id, menu_id) values (1,1);
insert into user_has_menu (user_id, menu_id) values (1,3);
```

Second insert statement is not executed as user_id must be unique.

Note: If I create new diagram in MySQL Workbench, everything is working fine and the SQL generated is without problematic UNIQUE constraints.

How can I remove those constraints without creating new diagram?

Comment: Might I suggest you use an auto-incremented primary key and just put a unique index on `user_id, menu_id`?

Comment: It is a workaround, however I want to know why does it not work in my diagram, and in newly created one the same scenario generates good SQL code. Futhermore, I have a lot of simlar agregation tables in my schema and I do not want to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

first find the unique constraint names:

```
select * 
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    and table_schema = 'my_database' 
    and table_name = 'my_table'
```

then drop them

```
alter table my_table drop index my_contraint
```

---

And because [unique constraints are handled as indexes on MySQL](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/drop-unique-constraint-in-mysql/) you can try make sure you don't have these indexes on the MySQL graphical interface.

Comment: It is just another workaround, I would like MySQL Workbench to generate code without those UNIQUE constraints. As you can see in the picture (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3843729/indexes.png) I do not have those constraints specified anywhere.

Comment: a can see a **type index on the FKs**... see if you can remove it, perhaps try to edit the connection between the tables. I think I told you to try remove them on the graphical interface, If you can't then you will have to *manually* drop these constraints.

Comment: I cannot remove them on GUI.. What is extremely strange is that when I create new diagram and put the same exact tables and create connection, the SQL code does not generate those UNIQUE constraints. I know |I can remove them manually, but it is not the case as I want the generated SQL code to be OK as I am modifing database quite a lot.

Comment: Yes, please find attach the results: https://www.dropbox.com/s/21xdnffxlh7zxw1/index_delete.png

Comment: then delete the fks, then add the indexes (to the columns to be referenced), then add the foreign keys.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I know..but it is just yet another workaround.. I want to understand why if I create **new diagram** with **the same tables** and link them **in the same way** the code which is generated is **OK**? I do not have to remove keys, manual add indexes etc..